# Aligning divs with just display inline and inline-block

Tags: html, css

```css
.box {
    background: maroon;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}
.box-1 {
    border: 5px solid black;
}
.box-2 {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 5px double black;
}
.box-3 {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 5px dashed black;
}
.box-4 {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 5px dotted black;
}
.box-5 {
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
 <body>
      <div class="box box-1"></div>
      <div class="box box-2"></div>
      <div class="box box-3"></div>
      <div class="box box-4"></div>
      <div class="box box-5"></div>
  </body>
```

I'm having trouble with aligning the third and fourth div. As per the above code, I'm getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azo01.png). However, I've not styled the third and fourth div (that's what I'm asking here) and the desired style is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OcaU.png). I've told not to use flexbox or grid, and use just only box model's basic display properties like `inline` and `inline-block`.

Comment: You can add `<br/>` tag between third and fourth `div` or any position you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another DIV for rows and make your boxes all "display: inline-block;"

```css
.box-row {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #00FF00;
}

.box {
    display: inline-block;
    background: maroon;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
}
.box-1 {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 5px solid black;
}
.box-2 {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 5px double black;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.box-3 {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 5px dashed black;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.box-4 {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 5px dotted black;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
.box-5 {
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
 <body>
      <div class="box-row">
        <div class="box box-1"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="box-row">
        <div class="box box-2"></div>
        <div class="box box-3"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="box-row">
        <div class="box box-4"></div>
        <div class="box box-5"></div>
      </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use float:

```css
.box {
  background: maroon;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.box-1 {
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.box-2 {
  clear: left; /* start a new line here */
  border: 5px double black;
}

.box-3 {
  border: 5px dashed black;
}

.box-4 {
  clear: left; /* and here */
  border: 5px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box-1"></div>
<div class="box box-2"></div>
<div class="box box-3"></div>
<div class="box box-4"></div>
<div class="box box-5"></div>
```

Using inline-block you can try like below:

```css
.box {
  background: maroon;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.box-1 {
  display:block;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

.box-2 {
  border: 5px double black;
}

.box-3 {
  border: 5px dashed black;
}


.box-4 {
  display:inline;
}
.box-4::before {
  content:"\A";
  white-space:pre;
}
.box-4::after {
  content:"";
  border: 5px dotted black;
  background: maroon;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box box-1"></div>
<div class="box box-2"></div>
<div class="box box-3"></div>
<div class="box-4"></div>
<div class="box box-5"></div>
```